# WCF C#. Издатель события внутри реализованного контракта, для оповещения UI сервера

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

Здравствуйте.
Интересует вопрос как оповещать UI самого сервиса при взаимодействии с клиентом?

> Контракт

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPcTableContract
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Task<bool> GetDisplayData(UniversalDisplayType displayData);


        ISubject<InputDataSend> StatChange { get;}
    }
```

> Сервис

```
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class PcService : IPcTableContract

    {
        #region ctor

        public PcService()
        {
            StatChange = new Subject<InputDataSend>();
        }

        #endregion



        #region ImplementsIPcTableContract

        public Task<bool> GetDisplayData(UniversalDisplayType displayData)
        {
          //Генерация события. хочу оповестить UI сервиса.
          StatChange.OnNext(new InputDataSend(displayData));  

          await Task.Delay(100);
          return true;
        }

        public ISubject<InputDataSend> StatChange { get;  }

        #endregion
    }
```

> создание сервиса

```
            string baseAddress = "http://localhost:4000/Service";
            service = new ServiceHost(typeof(PcService), new Uri(baseAddress));


            //IContract EndPoint
            WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None, true);
            binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
            binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
            binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);       //таймаут на Запрос-ответ
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 25);   //время жизни сесии (при бездействии клиентов)
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint = service.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPcTableContract), binding, "");

            service.Open();
```

Как подписаться на событие StatChange? Ведь у экземпляра ServiceHost уже нет доступа к контракту (интрефейсу)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант 1.** Передавайте не тип реализации сервиса - а экземпляр:

```
impl = new PcService();
service = new ServiceHost(impl, new Uri(baseAddress));
```

Я думаю, у вас не будет никаких проблем с тем чтобы подписаться на событие у конкретного экземпляра.

**Вариант 2.** Добавьте к ServiceEndpoint поведение (behavior), которое назначит пользовательский `InstanceProvider`. Этот `InstanceProvider` будет иметь доступ к создаваемым экземплярам сервиса - а значит, сможет подписаться на событие.

Comment: Спасибо!!! я так понял первый вариант работает если сервис синглтон? А если сервис создается на сессию, то использовать 2-ой вариант. А можно привести пример второго варианта!!

Comment: @Aldmi ну да. Более того, если мне не изменяет память, то без перегрузки InstanceContextProvider сервис-синглтон по-другому и не сделать.

Comment: Нет. тип сервиса задается атрибутом [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]. и создавать ServiceHost используя готовый готовый экземпляр сервиса можно, только если служба синглетная. Если сессия, то фабрика ServiceHost сама создает экземпляры на каждого клиента сесии. Дак как быть если сервис сессионный? т.е. чтобы каждый можно было подписаться на каждый экземпляр сервиса в сесии.

Comment: @Aldmi задается-то он задается, но если задать Single и передать тип вместо экземпляра - будет ошибка в рантайме.

Comment: @Aldmi если сервис сессионный - задайте свой InstanceProvider

Comment: Понял, спасибо. дальше уже поищу как это сделать)